# Throughput between MacOS and Windows devices limited to 100Mbps, how do I remove the bottleneck?

Tags: network, ethernet, file-transfer

I am using an M1 MacBook Air on the latest OS Update and a Windows 11 desktop PC and I would like to move files between them in the realm of a couple of GiB (1-100, so transfer speeds do matter).

They are connected in the same Network via either ethernet Cat6 or Wifi 5GHz (for testing and stability I used ethernet, but in theory 5GHz Wifi would be plenty). The network includes a router and the Windows machines are connected via one dumb ethernet switch (i.e. non-configurable), all 1000Base-T, machines verified to be connected and recognise that.

The issue: Throughput between MacOS and Windows is limited to 100Mbps.
I can't figure out where the bottleneck is and how to resolve this.

Multiple restarts etc. didn't yield any results, different programs and transfer protocols didn't either.
I used iperf on all machines - MacOS and Windows have a throughput of around 96Mbps and Windows to Windows the expected 980Mbps.
Any tips, something I overlooked? A setting? Maybe someone has a recommendation for a (free) software solution to easily share files between the systems?

Comment: How are you interfacing via ethernet on the Mac (obviously an adapter)?  What speed is the ethernet interface connected at, on the Mac?  Are the Mac and the Windows PC in the same network, or does traffic have to cross a router to get between them?

Comment: Mac is either USB-C dock with Gigabit ethernet -> Router -> Switch -> Windows or Mac (wifi 5GHz) -> Router -> Switch -> Windows. I checked in the Mac Network settings that it is using 1000Base-T by manually choosing it. They are in the same network (router has all ports and wifi in one network group, they can freely pass packages along and see each other)

Comment: So all the Windows machines are on the switch, but the Mac has to cross the router?

Comment: Ok yeah it was a hassle to test this, but as soon as I typed it out I knew I had to. Surprise surprise, the throughput is drastically improved. 756Mbps, which is fine, but 1) still 200 odd Mbps short of the other machines and 2) only wired in a way that can't stay like that. Unfortunately, it has to go through the router in any case ( It is a TP-LINK Archer VR2800, should deliver 2000+Mbps on 5GHz and 1000 on LAN ports, but somehow doesn't.)

Comment: Well, it's a TP-Link, so you can't expect much of it.

Comment: If this is an issue with the router, it is most likely off-topic here. You *could* try to run the Windows-Windows connection via the router as well to see whether it is only with the router.